# Combining "i.e." with "in this example"

Tags: word-choice, compound-sentences

I wonder whether it is ok to combine *i.e.* or *that is* with *in this example*. Consider that an example meeting situation has been described already and John has been introduced. The document also describes other examples so I tend to use *in this example*.

The following sounds good for me:

> The task of writing meeting minutes is up to the person who last joins the meeting, **in this example that is** John.

While this one doesn't:

> The task of writing meeting minutes is up to the person who last joins the meeting, **in this example i.e.** John.

Putting *i.e.* in front might solve it:

> The task of writing meeting minutes is up to the person who last joins the meeting, **i.e. in this example** John.

**Which alternatives are ok? Or would you generally recommend to not use *i.e.* and *in example* together, because *i.e.* is thought for explanations which has no exceptions? If it is preferred to not use them together, what is a better replacement to make clear that the conclusion is related to the example in this chapter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would favour the last one, either in the form of 'i.e., in this example, John'; or 'that is, in this example, John'.

I see nothing wrong with using 'i.e.' or 'that is' in conjunction with 'in this example'. Indeed it is essential to what you want to say.

Comment: It seems I didn't care about commas too much :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for one of the two below as it does not involve any violations to rules :

1. The task of writing meeting minutes is up to the person who last joins the meeting, in this case that is John.
2. The task of writing meeting minutes is up to the person who last joins the meeting, in this example that person is John.

The first one is the most appropriate of the three :

The task of writing meeting minutes is up to the person who last joins the meeting, in this example that is John.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use both, don't put them next to each other.  This sounds far better:

> The task of writing meeting minutes is up to the person who last joins the meeting, i.e. John in this example